# Google Calendar and the end of Daylights Savings Time

Tags: google-calendar-api

Let's say my timezone is America/Chicago. When Daylights Savings Time ends on Nov 1st, the clock will tick from `1:59:59 CDT (UTC -05:00)` to `1:00:00 CST (UTC -06:00)`, if I understand DST correctly.

This means that on Nov 1st, there will be be two instances of the time span 1am to 1:59:59am. When I create an event in Google Calendar on Nov 1st from 1:30am to 1:45am, how does it know which span of 15min I'm referring to?

Naturally, it seems like the way to distinguish between the first instance of 1:30am to 1:45am America/Chicago and the second instance of 1:30am to 1:45am America/Chicago is by associating their respective offset (UTC -05:00 and UTC -06:00, respectively).

The issue is that Google Calendar doesn't seem to deal with offsets, only timezones, but in this case there are two different instances of 1:30am to 1:45am America/Chicago since the America/Chicago has two different offsets (UTC -05:00 DST, UTC -06:00 ST).

[image]

Am I missing something, or is this an edge case / UI issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on the user's perspective. As you can see in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064?hl=en&visit_id=637293632199498342-1031373828&rd=1):

> You can change your time zone and create events in certain time zones. No matter where you create an event, everyone will see it in their own time zone. This can help with travel plans or make it easy to create events for people around the world.

Calendar uses UTC Time Zone, so:

> When events are created, they're converted into UTC, but you'll always see them in your local time.

This means your event at -5:00 UTC from 1:30am to 1:45 am will show up at that time, and after the Time Change it will not be there anymore, as the time changes at 1:59:59 *after the event has ended*.

In the case your event went from 1:50am to "2:15am", with the Time Change it would actually start at `-5 UTC 1:50` and end at `-6 UTC 1:15`.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. Do you know how I would create two events, one at 1:30am to 1:45am UTC -05:00 and one at 1:30am to 1:45am UTC -06:00? Your answer seems to imply that I could only create the former event, but not the latter.

Comment: Yeah, create one at 1:30 to 1:45 and another at 2:30 to 2:45am so when the Time changes at 1:59:59am the second will be at 1:30 and 1:45am